# Resizing and modifying the backround image in the folder/lower part of the page

Tags: css, image, image-resizing

I am trying the create a page, where the picture (of fruits) would be a background picture for the folder/lower part of the page space. It should range from the beginning to the end (width being 100% and height being about 30%). How could I make it work? Here is my code:

The problem is that the image of fruits stays as giant although it's height should only be 30% of the view and it's width is not 100%.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <!-- Links of sosial media      -->
  <a class="instagram" href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/38-instagram-256.png" width="35" height="35" alt=""></a>
    <a class="facebook" href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wpzoom-developer-icon-set/500/01-256.png" width="35" height="35" alt=""></a>
      <a class="twitter" href="#">
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/font-awesome/1792/twitter-square-256.png" width="35" height="35" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <div class="container"> 
      <div class="main>
        <h2 style="color: black" align="center"></h2> 
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/19/07/44/browser-773215__480.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" width="317" height="250"/>
        <b></b><b></b>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lacus eros, sodales vel facilisis at, sagittis vitae dolor. Nullam nec lacinia nibh, in dignissim ante. Cras ut egestas velit. Vestibulum ut porttitor quam. Sed dignissim ac lacus id ullamcorper.</p>

      <p style margin-bottom:"6px">Check:</p>
      <!-- Main-class ends below -->
      </div>
      <!--Footer-class starts. Height should be about 30% of the page view and width 100%. -->
      <div class="footer">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/21/21/33/fruit-2428678__480.jpg" class ="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the style.css-file. I tried to edit the image using this file.

```
h1{

}

#h1{
    color:blue;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    font-family: CelebriSans;
}

h2{
    font-family: CelebriSans;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.navbar{
background-color:#c99ab1 !important;
height:11%;
}

.main{
    height:60%;
    width:100%;
}

p{
font-family: CelebriSans;
font-size:16px; 
font-style:bold;
}

.footer{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:100%;
    height:30%;

}

.footer .img-fluid{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:100%;
    height:30%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the image an ID

```
<div class="footer">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/21/21/33/fruit-2428678__480.jpg" class ="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" id="test-img">
        </div>
```

And then in your CSS you should be able to change its properties how you want e.g.

```
#test-img {
  height: 300px;
}
```

It is also not full width because when i inspect your page it is showing

```
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

which is making a margin the whole way around your page